# issue in Kerberos authentication when accessing through load balancer for IIS servers

Tags: .net, iis, kerberos

I have setup load balancer dns for IIS servers and set spn for load balancer in AD. Even after enabling applicationPool to true and kernal mode to false in the applicationPool properties, I get below kerberos error:

{
"Depth": 0,
"ClassName": "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException",
"Message": "The NetworkCredentials provided were unable to create a Kerberos credential, see inner exception for details.",
"Source": "System.IdentityModel",
"StackTraceString": "   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.KerberosRequestorSecurityToken..ctor(String servicePrincipalName, TokenImpersonationLevel tokenImpersonationLevel, NetworkCredential networkCredential, String id, SafeFreeCredentials credentialsHandle, ChannelBinding channelBinding)\r\n   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.KerberosSecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelbinding)\r\n   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.KerberosSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)\r\n   at CobraLux.Clients.ApiConnect.ApiConnectExtensions.GetKerberosTicket(Uri uri) in D:\app\ADO\Y88681.2\_work\4102\s\src\CobraLux.Clients\ApiConnect\ApiConnectExtensions.cs:line 57\r\n   at .....",
"RemoteStackTraceString": null,
"RemoteStackIndex": 0,
"ExceptionMethod": {
"Name": ".ctor",
"AssemblyName": "System.IdentityModel",
"AssemblyVersion": "4.0.0.0",
"AssemblyCulture": "",
"ClassName": "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.KerberosRequestorSecurityToken",
"Signature": "Void .ctor(System.String, System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel, System.Net.NetworkCredential, System.String, System.IdentityModel.SafeFreeCredentials, System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ChannelBinding)",
"MemberType": 1
},
"HResult": -2146233087,
"HelpURL": null
},

{
"Depth": 1,
"ClassName": "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException",
"Message": "InitializeSecurityContent failed. Ensure the service principal name is correct.",
"Source": "System.IdentityModel",
"StackTraceString": "   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.KerberosRequestorSecurityToken.Initialize(TokenImpersonationLevel tokenImpersonationLevel, NetworkCredential networkCredential, SafeFreeCredentials credentialsHandle, ChannelBinding channelBinding)\r\n   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.KerberosRequestorSecurityToken..ctor(String servicePrincipalName, TokenImpersonationLevel tokenImpersonationLevel, NetworkCredential networkCredential, String id, SafeFreeCredentials credentialsHandle, ChannelBinding channelBinding)",
"RemoteStackTraceString": null,
"RemoteStackIndex": 0,
"ExceptionMethod": {
"Name": "Initialize",
"AssemblyName": "System.IdentityModel",
"AssemblyVersion": "4.0.0.0",
"AssemblyCulture": "",
"ClassName": "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.KerberosRequestorSecurityToken",
"Signature": "Void Initialize(System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel, System.Net.NetworkCredential, System.IdentityModel.SafeFreeCredentials, System.Security.Authentication.ExtendedProtection.ChannelBinding)",
"MemberType": 8
},
"HResult": -2146233087,
"HelpURL": null
},

{
"Depth": 2,
"ClassName": "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception",
"Message": "No credentials are available in the security package",
"Source": null,
"StackTraceString": null,
"RemoteStackTraceString": null,
"RemoteStackIndex": 0,
"HResult": -2147467259,
"HelpURL": null
}

Comment: Consider formatting your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting It makes reading your post easier

Comment: I found a solution to a similar error in the Microsoft documentation, you can refer to it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20170201-live-migration-via-constrained-delegation-with-kerberos-in-windows-server-2016